# jQuery Scrollbar Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

Hi I am stucked in my big project using the custom scrollbar. None of the plugins are 100% working or I may be unaware of some plugins.

which jQuery scroll bar plugin is best? in given list of circumstances below.

1. proper touch / scroll (cross browser and device compatibility)
2. nested conditions
3. inside popup and inside drop down.
4. inside ajax updated contents
5. resize / orientation scenarios
6. for devices: auto focusing for input inside popup
7. supported in major devices including samsung low end touch phones.

Has any one using this type of custom scrollbar which is perfect for all type of my scenarios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using the plugin by Malihu. It does the job pretty well and have dozen of options so you can personalize it. I think it passes all your requirements.

http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/

Comment: yes i have tried this one..  this one is best among others.  but i am seeing an issue in this.. could you help on that small issue..    Issue is when scrolling inside the scrollbar ..    sometimes the content is not scrolling but the body does

Comment: In my projects it scrolls the body only if the scrollable div was scrolled to the very bottom. Post a fiddle so I can try to help You with your issue.

Comment: it works better in desktop, not an issue.   But the issue is related to touch devices(iPhone, iPad, etc.,) could you check and confirm.... is the same page having that issue in devices though? please

Comment: I've checked the plugin demo page on my Android phones and all the demos work correctly and as i said - the body is scrolling **only** after the scrollbar have been scrolled to the very bottom. The only issue I noticed on phones is that it works a little bit laggy, scrolling is not perfectly smooth.